# When is a Markov of order 1 a Martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales, markov-process

I have two questions and I am very confused about the concepts

Can a **Markov process of order one** also be a a Martingale?
Is any **Markov process of order one** also a Martingale?
For 1. I would say yes, since a Markov of order one is also an AR(1) it would be a martingale if c=0 and phi=1. However, I am very confused about the second. My answer for 2 would be no, but I cannot explain it properly.

Can anyone maybe help me?

Comment: Please, be so kind to tell us what you're talking about. What does "order" mean, or $c=0, \phi=1$? AR(1) is not a generally recognized notion, either.

Comment: Hello, I justed wanted to know if a Markov of order 1 is a martingale and if any markov of order 1 can be a martingale ? with AR(1) I mean autoregressive process of order 1, c is the constant in the process and phi the parameter.

Comment: Please, whatever page in whatever book you're looking at, we can't see it. Include the relevant definitions in your question, if it's not too much to ask.

Comment: Hello, I am not referring to any book. My question just consists of whether a Markov of order 1 is a Martingale and if any Markov of order 1 can be a martingale. I think the AR(1) part is irrelevant if you have an opinion on the two questions since the AR(1) is just my thought.

Comment: As long as you can't or won't define your "Markov order 1", you're just wasting people's time. Maybe there are some people knowing your specific terminology, but whether they read your question (and can be bothered) is mere luck.

Comment: First-Order Markov Chains= the probability of a future state depends only on the current state. Sorry I thought since it is the math stack, you would be familiar with the terminology

Comment: That is not standard terminology.  The standard definition of a Markov chain is that the probability of the future state depends only on the current state, so the "first order" would be redundant.  Additionally, the $c$ and $\phi$ you mention in your question are notation which you cannot expect everyone to be familiar with.  It's likely there are people who could answer but use different notation for whatever $c$ and $\phi$ refer to and therefore can't help without you including the definitions in the question.

Comment: hello, I did not intend to offend you all. In the comment above I defined what I meant with Markof of order one, and I add that you can leave out c and phi, since the important question I wanted to know was whether a markov of order 1 is martingale and if any markov of order 1 can be martingale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @RobertIsrael shows that the Markov property does not imply the martingale property, even when the Markov chain has order one.

As for the relevance to autoregressive processes:

An AR(1) process $(X_t)$ (where $t$ is a discrete time index) satisfies
$$
X_{t+1} = c + \phi X_t + \varepsilon_{t+1}\tag1
$$
It follows that every AR(1) process is Markov of order one, since the distribution of $X_{t+1}$ given $X_1,X_2,\ldots ,X_t$ is the same as the distribution of $X_{t+1}$ given $X_t$. Taking conditional expectations of (1) given $X_t$, we get:
$$
E(X_{t+1} \mid X_t) = c + \phi X_t\tag2
$$
This tells us that an AR(1) process is **not** a martingale except in the special case when $c=0$ and $\phi=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A first-order Markov chain can be a martingale, but need not be.  In order for it to be a martingale, you need $\mathbb E[X_{n+1} | X_n] = X_n$.  So for example a simple unbiased random walk (equal probability of steps of $+1$ and $-1$) is a martingale.  If you want it to be a finite Markov chain on states $a, \ldots, b$, make $a$ and $b$ absorbing.
On the other hand, a biased random walk is not a martingale.

Comment: so can I say that a markov of order one is a martingale, since for Markov order one it holds that  P[X_t+1|X_t,...X_2,X_1]= P[X_t+1|X_t] so the future states depends on the current value. The only thing that confuses me is, Martingale uses expectation and Markov uses probability. So how are these things equivalent to each other?